# This type of file can harm your computer, trying to download an .ini file in Chrome using c# and selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, download

THE ABOVE SOLUTION IS IN PYTHON BUT I AM writing code in C#!!!
There is an icon on my application to download a .ini file.  Through research the only solutions are in python and ruby but I am using c# with selenium. I have scoured google and stackoverflow but there is no solution! When I click the icon I get the following message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99PnN.png)

"This type of file can harm your computer.  Do you want to keep the ahdsfhewf.ini file anyway"  Then it gives you a choice Keep or Discard.

How can I get rid of this chrome pop up in my code?  And also confirm its downloaded?

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", false);
            options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
```

I have also come across this code in python so if someone can convert it to c# this would be great:

```
print('Starting..')
prefs = {
'download.default_directory': 'C:\\Users\MainDesk\Downloads',
'download.prompt_for_download': False,
'download.extensions_to_open': 'xml',
'safebrowsing.enabled': False
}

options = Options()

options.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='C:\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Again this looks promising but I need it in c# not python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

prefs = {
'download.default_directory': 'C:/Utility/Downloads/',
'download.prompt_for_download': False,
'download.extensions_to_open': 'xml',
'safebrowsing.enabled': True
}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection")
options.add_argument("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.landxmlproject.org/file-cabinet")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='MntnRoad.xml']//following::span[1]//a[text()='Download']"))).click()
```

First I don't want the pop up and secondly I want to confirm its downloaded.

Comment: This is not a duplicate the xml file is written in python but I am wriitng in C#