# Download .xml file with selenium chrome driver

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download am xml file with selenium chrome driver, but getting but prompted for:

> "this type of file can harm your computer.Do you want to keep the file anyway?".

Using Google Version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (32-bit) and ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106. 
The powershell chrome option I am using is below:

```bsh
$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$ChromeOptions.AddArguments(@(
    "--disable-extensions",
    "--ignore-certificate-errors"))

$download = "C:\temp\download"
$ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");
$ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", $download);
$ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
$ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", "true");

$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($chromeOptions)
```

I'd appreciate the correct option to remove the prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? 
Just use the built-in PowerShell cmdlets to do this. 
Invoke-WebRequest, Start-BitTransfer, or the .Net namespace.

You don't need a browser to scrape a web site or download a file. 
Point of note: Some site blocks any automated effort, regardless of the tool you try to use.

> [3 ways to download files with PowerShell](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)

```
# 1. Invoke-WebRequest

$url = "http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/10meg.test"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\10meg.test"
$start_time = Get-Date

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"


# 2. System.Net.WebClient

$url = "http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/10meg.test"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\10meg.test"
$start_time = Get-Date

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
#OR
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)

Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"


# 3. Start-BitsTransfer

$url = "http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/10meg.test"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\10meg.test"
$start_time = Get-Date

Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output

#OR
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Asynchronous

Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"


# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Examples
<#
# Built-In Examples

$R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://www.bing.com?q=how+many+feet+in+a+mile
$R.AllElements | where {$_.innerhtml -like "*=*"} | Sort { $_.InnerHtml.Length } | Select InnerText -First 5
shortest HTML value often helps you find the most specific element that matches that text.
$R=Invoke-WebRequest http://www.facebook.com/login.php -SessionVariable fb
$FB
$Form = $R.Forms[0]
$Form | Format-List
$Form.fields
$Form.Fields["email"]="User01@Fabrikam.com"
$R=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://www.facebook.com" + $Form.Action) -WebSession $FB -Method POST -Body $Form.Fields
# Sends a sign-in request by running the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. The command specifies a value of "fb" for the SessionVariable parameter, and saves the 
$R.StatusDescription
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973757(v=vs.85).aspx").Links.Href
#>
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Online



(Get-Command -Name Start-BitsTransfer).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Start-BitsTransfer).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Start-BitsTransfer -Examples
<#
# Built-In Examples

Start-BitsTransfer -Source "http://server01/servertestdir/testfile1.txt" -Destination "c:\clienttestdir\testfile1.txt"
Import-CSV filelist.txt | Start-BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "c:\clienttestdir\testfile1.txt" -Destination "http://server01/servertestdir/testfile1.txt" -TransferType Upload
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "http://server01/servertestdir/testfile1.txt", "http://server01/servertestdir/testfile2.txt" -Destination 
$Cred = Get-Credential
 Start-BitsTransfer -DisplayName MyJob -Credential $Cred -Source "http://server01/servertestdir/testfile1.txt" -Destination "c:\clienttestdir\testfile1.txt"
Import-CSV filelist.txt | Start-BitsTransfer -Asynchronous -Priority Normal
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "http://server01/servertestdir/*.*" -Destination "c:\clienttestdir\"
Import-CSV filelist.txt | Start-BitsTransfer -TransferType Upload
Start-BitsTransfer -Source .\Patch0416.msu -Destination $env:temp\Patch0416.msu -ProxyUsage Override -ProxyList BitsProxy:8080 -ProxyCredential 
#>
Get-help -Name Start-BitsTransfer -Full
Get-help -Name Start-BitsTransfer -Online


<#
WebClient Class

Definition 
Namespace: System.Net
Assembly:  System.Net.WebClient.dll

Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-3.1



WebClient.DownloadFile Method

Namespace: System.Net
Assembly:  System.Net.WebClient.dll

Downloads the resource with the specified URI to a local file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netcore-3.1
#>
```

Though if you truly want to do this with Selenium via Chrome, then this similar SO thread should be of help.

> [How to control the download of files with Selenium + Python bindings in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654358/how-to-control-the-download-of-files-with-selenium-python-bindings-in-chrome)
>
> As well as this article and sample:
>
> [PowerShell & Selenium: Automate Web Browser Interactions – Part
>   II](https://tech.mavericksevmont.com/blog/powershell-selenium-automate-web-browser-interactions-part-ii/)

As for this warning ...

***> "this type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to keep the file anyway?".***

... this is not PowerShell or a PowerShell warning, this is the Windows and the Browser (IE, Edge, Chrome, et all) alerting you to a potential threat.

> [Working around the Google Chrome "This type of file can harm your
>   computer" problem](https://www.majorgeeks.com/news/story/working_around_the_google_chrome_this_type_of_file_can_harm_your_computer_problem.html)
>
> Google announced recently that it made the decision to improve
>   protection against unwanted software downloads in the Chrome browser
>   and Google search.

See these SO thread as well on this topic.

> [How to disable 'This type of file can harm your computer' pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up)
>
> [This type of file can harm your computer, trying to download an .ini file in Chrome using c# and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963842/this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-trying-to-download-an-ini-file-in-chr?noredirect=1)

Comment: Thanks and much helpful. Appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, always various ways to do X or Y.

Answer (score 1):

Download .xml file with selenium Edge driver using sendkeys :-

SendKeys.Send("^j");
Thread.Sleep(3000);

SendKeys.Send("^j");
Thread.Sleep(3000);

SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
Thread.Sleep(3000);

SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).